# FSCalendar hide next previous months labels swift

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar, fscalendar

I have implemented `FSCalendar` for dates but I need to hide next previous month labels only. I have marked red in image attached for reference.

actually I have tried all properties but couldn't find it. I know for not showing last month dates I am using `calendar.placeholderType = .none` but I need to remove next previous month label. like as we are in current month which is `MARCH` but I dont want to show only label or Title of FEB or APR.

FEB --  MAR  -- APR

I am using FSCalendar in swift 5.

[image: FSCalendar]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use Following code will fix you issues:

```
calendarView.appearance.headerMinimumDissolvedAlpha = 0
```

Comment: One thing does `FSCalendar` supports next previous button or I have to create my own custom buttons?

Comment: You have to create your own and need to set as per month alignment.

Comment: just a quick thing if you knows, if I select any date in `FSCalendar` is there any possibility I can change today date label color  only. Like today is 5 and what If I selected 2 March then 5 of today title or label color would be of any color like blue. Any idea?

Comment: @NewBieMobile Yes it is possible

Comment: @teja_D can you please guide me for that ?

Comment: @NewBieMobile Ask a question and ping, so I can post some well formatted code.

Comment: @teja_D  Here's the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60544580/only-change-of-todays-date-label-or-title-color-in-fscalendar-swift